# printf prints the nsstring right after releasing allocated nsstring

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Why print works after relasing nsstring

```
NSString * newname = [[NSString alloc] init];
newname = @"aaaa";

[newname release];

printf("%s", newname.UTF8String);
```

Comment: It's constant string. You can't release it. Change it to `newname = [@"aaaa" mutableCopy];` and you will see difference.

Comment: @Cy-4AH is exactly right: `@"aaaa"` is a string _constant_, and it produces an "immortal" `NSString` object. It simply ignores `-release` messages entirely. (@Cy-4AH, I think your comment is worth being an answer, if you'd like to post one.)

Comment: Your code also suggests a misunderstanding about assignment. Since this is manually memory managed, you're leaking the original `newname`. You create an `NSString` in line one. Line two drops that entirely without releasing it (so it leaks), and assigns this constant NSString to `newname`. Then you send a release to that constant (which is technically ignored, but that's an implementation detail). And then you access the value after releasing it, which is undefined behavior. (There's no promise this will crash. It can do anything at all, and in this case it "works" by printing.)

Comment: Sending the `release` message does not mean "reduce the retain count by one." It means, "I no longer care about this object." There are many similar cases where the object may not be deallocated just because you have released it as many times as you've retained it. (For example, there may be pending autorelease calls, which are extremely common, or it may be one of the "small" NSNumbers that are implemented as singletons.)